# Two modals, each only work on second click of buttons

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, modal-dialog

I want to write a page with two pop-up modals. I have code, that works as I require but only on the 2nd click of each button. Much of this is copied from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp.

I have put the page up on the web, http://test.davelevy.info/modals/index.html.

Here's the CSS,

```
.modal { display: none; /* Hidden by default */ position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */ padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0; top: 0; width: 30%; /* Full width */ height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
        
/* Modal Content */
.modal-content { background-color: #fefefe; 
    margin: 5px; font-size: 80%; padding: 5px; width: 80%; border: 1px solid #888; }
        
/* The Close Button */
.close { color: #aaaaaa; float: right; font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; }    
.close:hover, .close:focus { color: #000; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; }
    
.modal-content2 {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */ background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto; padding: 20px; border: 1px solid #888; width: 80%;
}
.close2 { color: #aaaaaa; float: right; font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; }
.close2:hover, .close2:focus { color: #000; text-decoration: none;cursor: pointer; }
```

Here's the HTML

```
<h1>This is a two modal test</h1>
<p>The 2nd Button, strangly</p>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn2" onclick="showmodal('myModal2','myBtn2','close2')">More Latin</button>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal"><!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content" style="width: 80%;"> 
        <span class="close2">×</span>
        <p style="font-size: 120%;">A 2nd example modal</p>
        <p style="font-size: 102%;">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
</div>
</div>

<hr>

<p>And no 1</p>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn" onclick="showmodal('myModal','myBtn','close')">Click Me</button>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p style="font-size: 120%;">An example modal</p>
    <p style="font-size: 102%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

And here's the javascript,

```
<script>
// Get the modal  
function showmodal (id,bid,clid) {
   var modal = document.getElementById(id);
// Get the button that opens the modal
   var btn = document.getElementById(bid);
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
   var span = document.getElementsByClassName(clid)[0];
// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
   btn.onclick = function() { modal.style.display = "block"; }
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { modal.style.display = "none"; }
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    } 
}
</script>
```

How to make this happen on the first click?

A stretch goal would be how to reuse the .close css rule?

I have looked for an answer on the site, but those that seem close to the problem definition have very code specific answers; I have not found one that helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i simplified it a bit, by using event listeners instead and removing the onclicks from the HTML.

```
function showmodal() {
    var modal = document.querySelector("#myModal");
    var btn = document.querySelector("#myBtn");
    var span = document.querySelector(".close");

    btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    });

    //span.onclick = function () { modal.style.display = "none"; }
    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        //console.log(event.target);
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
showmodal();

    <p>And no 1</p>
    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <button id="myBtn"> Click Me</button>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">×</span>
            <p style="font-size: 120%;">An example modal</p>
            <p style="font-size: 102%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
                esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
                qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have adjusted this to work.